# How to mathematically prove that the continuous data is better for finding out the correlations than the binary data?

Tags: binary, correlation, normal-distribution

If I want to calculate the correlations among the components in a vector space using the MLE with a prior of multivariate Normal distribution, which kind of data should be better?

- The binary data

  or
- The continuous data

Such as the binary data `{(1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1),...,(1, 1, 1, 0)}`, and the continuous data `{(0.9, 0.1, 0, 0), (0.8, 0, 0.1, 0.1), (0,1, 0,1, 0.4, 0.4), ... , (0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0)}`.

If the assumption is the data follows a 4-dimension multivariate Normal distribution, and the task is to find out the correlations between the 4 dimensions.

How to mathematically prove that which data style is better for the task under the above assumptions?

(binary data means that we just use the co-occurrence information, and continuous data means that we not only use the co-occurrence, but also take advantage of the different weight values in one sample.)

Comment: Maybe this fits better on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ ?